# c++ generalized operator templating

Tags: c++, templates, operators, overloading

I'm doing some numerical simulations where it is nice to overload operations on vectors (similar to valarrays). For example, I can write

```
template <typename T>
vector<T> operator*(const vector<T>& A, const vector<T>& B){
   //blah blah
}
```

But what if I want to generalize this template so as to act on two different types of vectors and (potentially) return a third type? I.e. I want to write

```
template <typename T, template U, template V>
vector<V> operator*(const vector<T>& A, const vector<U>& B){
   //blah blah
}
```

Now, the above does indeed work if I use the operator in a situation "A*B" where A and B are distinct types and return a another distinct type. However, if A and B are the same type, it does not work. Certainly I could define different templates for each combination (i.e. T only, or T and U only, or T, U, and V) but that seems ugly. Is there a way I can use a single template expression of the T,U, and V variety given above and make it work even if "A", "B", and "A*B" are all the same types (or have only 2 different types?)

Comment: i don't template argument deduction looks at the return value (you cannot overload on return types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, the above does indeed work if I use the operator in a situation
>   "A*B" where A and B are distinct and return a different type.

To be honest, this doesn't make sense. Your template shouldn't work at all because V cannot be deduced and it is the third template parameter. If you had written:

```
template <typename V, template T, template U>
vector<V> operator*(const vector<T>& A, const vector<U>& B){
   //blah blah
}
```

This would "work" but only if you explicitly specified V, something like

```
operator*<double>(A, B); //where A is vector<int> and B is vector<float>, for example
```

Surely you want to return a `vector<V>` where `V` is the type of the expression `T()*U()`. This is possible to do in C++11, but not trivially in C++03( I mean, you could do some type-traiting at best). Here's how it's done in C++11:

```
template <typename T, template U>
vector<decltype(T()*U())> operator*(const vector<T>& A, const vector<U>& B)  
{
   //blah blah
}
```

HTH

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Oops, copy-paste artifact :) It's not needed. Thanks

Comment: I also wonder about the utility of an operation whose return type you don't know. What will you do with this anonymous vector? Maybe it makes sense, but I feel uneasy about it.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: That's what auto is for :) `auto v = A*B;`

Comment: @Kerrek SB: For example, one might have a tensor being contracted with a vector, producing a matrix. (Admittedly I could use a generalized tensor class to represent all 3 types.)

Comment: @Armen: Well, yes, but *then* what do you do with `v`? You can't pass it into ordinary functions that expect a vector of a particular type. Templated iterator-based algorithms may be your only option...

Comment: @andyInCambridge: But why does that necessitate that the containers have different value *types*? Wouldn't they all just be `double`? Or are you writing tensors as vectors of vectors? I think there might be more elegant solutions for that.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Templated iterator-based algorithms ***are*** usually the best option. Also, it's not like you don't ***know***  the return type. You do if you know the types T and U. For example if T is int and U is double, the result is vector<double>..

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Rather than just have them be double*, I'm writing them as objects, so as to be able to call, tr(), det(), norm(), etc.

Comment: @andyInCambridge: I see. Perhaps the single operator-`*` is a bit ambiguous, though: Is a rank-(1,1) tensor times a rank-(1,0) one a (1,0) or a (2,1) tensor? Is the composition with the evaluation (the trace map) implicit? If not, lazy-evaluation classes may be useful, too, to avoid premature computations.

Answer (score 0):

This can work in C++0x with decltype.

```
template <typename T, template U> 
vector<decltype(declval<T>() + declval<U>())> 
operator*(const vector<T>& A, const vector<U>& B){
   //blah blah
}
```

Without using this mechanism- and presuming that T and U do not provide their own mechanism- you can't do something like this. You can only handle the situation where T, U, and the return type are all the same type. You can, however, deal with primitive types- there's a Boost type trait for the result of applying operators like `+` to various primitive types to find the promoted type.

Comment: Thanks, this answered my question also!

Comment: Why `+`? Shouldn't it be `*`?

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out you can use `decltype` to achieve this. C++0x also provides the template `common_type` which deduces a type to which all it template arguments can be coerced without any specific arithmetic operation. So it can also be used if no overloaded operators are available for the argument types.